# Concatenate regarding if variables

Tags: javascript, html, concatenation

so most of my coding is done however as some variables cannot be provided (undefined jQuery results)
the layout of the concatenation string will need to be dynamic and not static

eg. if there is no street number it should pass that variable and continue, and not insert the line breaks.

Current code (added commas to assist with Result explanation):

```
document.getElementById('fulla').value= streetNumber + ",\n" + streetName + ",\n" + suburb + ",\n" + city + ",\n" + state + ",\n" + country + ",\n" + zip;
```

Result:

```
null,<br>
Unnamed Road,<br>
Mabeskraal,<br>
null,<br>
North West,<br>
South Africa,<br>
0313<br>
```

So what I want it to do is just provide me with the rest without the `null` Value:

```
Unnamed Road,<br>
Mabeskraal,<br>
North West,<br>
South Africa,<br>
0313
```

Comment: someone's going to learn inline if else conditions today...

Comment: @AbdulJabbar : ... or not. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a little more control and save some repetition by stuffing everything into an array:

```
var addrLines = [streetNumber, streetName, suburb, city, state, country, zip];
```

[filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) away the nulls:

```
addrLines = addrLines.filter(function(line){return line!=null});
```

and [joining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) what's left

```
var addr = addrLines.join("\n");
```

Comment: That's a nicer answer than mine.  I keep forgetting about the ES5 array methods since I can't use them at work.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher There's nice polyfills in the docs if you need to go <IE9. Take a peek at the docs for [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)